# Estimates omitted once a variable is included in a formula in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

I have a model similar to the one shown in the example code below. My aim to include another variable (for example age) in the formula of the model. However, this code works as desired although the estimates for the variable included in the formula are omitted. Is it possible to display the corresponding estimates of this variable despite its inclusion in the formula. Any leads?

```
tbl_uv_ex1 <-
  tbl_uvregression(
    trial[c("response", "age", "grade")],
    method = glm,
    y = response,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
formula= "{y}~ {x}+ age"
  )
tbl_uv_ex1
```

Comment: This is the intended behavior of the function: it only displays the varying variable (eg `{x}`).  If the function also showed age, there would be multiple rows labelled as "age" and it would be difficult to know which model the rows belonged together.

Comment: To get what you seem to be after, you'll need to construct the models yourself, then you can pass each model to `tbl_regression()`. You can stack those tables using `tbl_stack()`.

Comment: This idea worked perfectly!!